# Perforce: How to take backup of other users pending changelist files

Tags: perforce

I want to take backup of all files inside a Pending changelists of an user (who left the company)
Please let me know is there any scripts to do that or any other way to do the activity.

Thanks in advance.

-karthik

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to their workstation?  If so, you can grab the files they were working on.  Unless they submitted or shelved their changes, the only copy of their work-in-progress is sitting on their workstation.

Comment: No, The user left the Organization already and so we dont have access to their workstation, please let me know is there any way to get the Checked out files backup.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier we were using the btgrab command for grabing the other person change just based on pending changelist number in Windows version of perforce. Unfortunately i don't have that script now.

Answer (score 0):

Checked out files are edited locally on the machine, not on the server. So the only place they are located is on the workstation. Unless the user was nice enough to shelve the changes.